# Need 32 Bit Apache on Red Hat 6.5 64bit

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, 64-bit

I have a Red Hat 6.5 Enterprise Server which is 64 bit. I have a 3rd party package that I use for Web Services that is an add-on to Apache Web Server. This package is 32 bit so I need to have a 32 bit Apache. Somehow I should be able to easily find a way to install such a server on a Red Hat server but I have not yet found the correct set of keywords to search for.

Is there a repository that I can use for this?

Has anyone else ran into this problem and can point me to a solution?

thanks 
dave

Comment: Get the 64-bit version of the package....or recompile/install the third party package.

Comment: do not have the source to recompile and would rather run 32 bit apache..

Comment: Not only will you need to install 32bit package, but also the libraries which are needed by the package to run.

Comment: you mean for apache?

Comment: Not only apache, but many system libraries!

Answer (score 0):

what purpose are you trying to achieve?, IMHO if  3rd party app does not support 64 BIT apache, why not keep it simply on 32 bit apache on 32 OS as well.